# Does anyone have issues with PhpStorm 2023.2.4 and Copilot unable to auth

Tags: github, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, github-copilot

Basically, it gets stuck here for 5 mins "Retrieving GitHub Device Code". Then when it does finish, all it gives me an Exception error from the Plugin in the bottom left. The problem is persisting on JetBrains IDEs that I use, not VSCode.

[image]

I have tried to reinstall the plugin, restart the computer but to no avail. The error remains regardless of what I do. It has started to happen since I updated my JetBrains IDE to recent versions. I googled and found out no one has such an issue, so not sure what's up.